# Слияние двух столбцов с разным временем

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два датафрейма, хочу произвести слияние по столбцу с Time первого файла (там часы), со столбцом второго файла Time, где минутки. Получится новый файл, где есть скажем 13 часов дня и у нему идут столбцы с минутками и значения их строк. Пример итоговый внизу, попробовал merge в разных видах сделать, что то не выходит, значит я чего то не знаю.

```
Date    Time    Count
20200601    110000  15767
20200601    120000  6649
20200601    130000  1415
20200601    140000  2272
20200601    150000  3092
20200601    160000  723
20200601    170000  2303
20200601    180000  2524
20200601    190000  671
20200601    210000  84572
20200601    220000  225204
20200601    230000  114821
20200602    0       39523
20200602    110000  95909
20200602    120000  233851
20200602    130000  182064
```

```
Date    Time    Cont 2
20200601    100100  475
20200601    100200  319
20200601    100300  400
20200601    100400  437
20200601    100500  308
20200601    100600  327
20200601    100700  256
20200601    100800  211
20200601    100900  8031
20200601    101000  120
20200601    101100  47
20200601    101200  101
20200601    101300  196
20200601    101400  181
20200601    101500  130
20200601    101600  240
20200601    101700  59
20200601    101800  109
20200601    101900  48
```

Что нужно получить:

```
Date    Time    Time 2  Count   Count 2
20200601    100000  105600  723 109
20200601    100000  105700  723 97
20200601    100000  105800  723 71
20200601    100000  105900  723 69
20200601    110000  110000  981 30
20200601    110000  110100  981 44
20200601    110000  110200  981 21
20200601    110000  110300  981 44
20200601    110000  110400  981 28
20200601    110000  110500  981 14
```

Файлы: http://file.sampo.ru/7k64j9/

Comment: вы словами опишите смысл слияния. потому как из ваших исходных совсем не понятно, как вы получили результат.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно будет сделать какой-то дополнительный столбец и объединять по нему. Но пока ничего непонятно

Comment: ничего не понятно все равно. добавьте пояснения в сам вопрос (редактировать), а не в комментарий к нему.

Comment: @Николай По объяснению вроде и понятно, но цифры в ваших таблицах как-то не бьются с объяснениями. Или в третьей таблице данные произвольные, не из первых двух таблиц?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, знатоки могут сделать ещё проще, а у меня, кажется, много лишних телодвижений, но в общем так:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')

# добавляем в df2 колонку с обрезанным до часа временем
df2['TimeHour'] = df2.Time.div(10000).astype(int).mul(10000)

# аналог FULL JOIN из SQL, Pandas поддерживает различные варианты JOIN
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on=['Date','Time'], right_on=['Date','TimeHour'], suffixes=['',' 2'])

# поскольку с обеих сторон есть данные, которым нет соответствия, возникли NA
# и данные стали float из-за NA, чиним это и выбираем нужные колонки
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)[['Date','Time','Time 2','Count','Cont 2']]

# сортируем что получилось
df = df.sort_values(['Date', 'Time', 'Time 2']).reset_index(drop='True')

# смотрим результат
df

    Date    Time    Time 2  Count   Cont 2
0   20200601    0   100100  0   475
1   20200601    0   100200  0   319
2   20200601    0   100300  0   400
3   20200601    0   100400  0   437
4   20200601    0   100500  0   308
... ... ... ... ... ...
2249    20200603    230000  234700  262931  943
2250    20200603    230000  234800  262931  770
2251    20200603    230000  234900  262931  2776
2252    20200603    230000  235000  262931  3372
2253    20200604    0   0   74757   0

2254 rows × 5 columns
```

Получилось не совсем как в вашем выводе, потому что и в `df1` есть дата/время, которым нет соответствия в `df2` и наоборот тоже. Там, где нет соответствия, там сейчас стоят нули.

Comment: @Николай Приведите пример. Я что-то не вижу пока, как это возможно. Надо смотреть на конкретные строки.

Comment: Сейчас всё перепроверю

Comment: Исправил. Надо было конечно джойнить по двум полям - не только по времени, но и по **дате**, а я совсем забыл. И ещё непонятно что делать там, где нет соответствия между одним df и другим, я сейчас сделал, чтобы всё показывало, но где нет соответствия, там нули.